# User icons not visible in chat using IE10?

Tags: support, chat

Using StackOverflow chat with IE10, only user icons which I've previously seen on the main site appear in the chat area and on user profiles. All other user icons do not load.

In Firefox and Chrome, all icons load. Any ideas?

(Clearing cache didn't solve this issue)

*Edit: This issue only seems to persist with Gravatar user icons. Those hosted on imgur are returning 304.*

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: Can you see the image URL? What happens when you browse directly to it?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yes, for example this URL loads if I browse directly to it (taken from Network tab of developer tools): http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/222630f327e8942d6c2b94d0210717ca?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - After I load it, it appears in his profile, but in Network tab of developer tools, IE is aborting requests to Gravatar.

Comment: Still looks like a browser cache issue. How did you try to clear its cache?

Comment: F12 Developer Tools -> Clear cache.

Comment: Disabling tracking lists worked. Sorry for wasting time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disabled Tracking Protection lists and this issue disappeared.

Specifically the Abine list was causing the issue.